# JQGrid - How can i reload the dataurl of one select based on another select

Tags: jqgrid

I have a JQgrid, i click to add a row and editform opens.
In the editform I have 2 select, loaded using php and mysql.
When I change the first select, i need to reload the 2nd select passing the new id.
I managed to make it work, but I lose bootstrap style and alignment. 
Could anybody help me? Id would be fine like i did but I just want to reload the new dataurl, I don't want to lose the style and alignment.

thank you!

[image: Before]
[image: After]

```
$("#gDett").jqGrid({
regional:lingua_attiva,     
url:'include/dettagli/grid_esiti_sped.php?idquery=1',    
datatype: "json",    
mtype: 'GET',
colNames:['ID', 
],
colModel :[ 
    {name:'ID', index:'ID', width:80, sortable:false, hidden:true}, 
 {name:'IdUtenteEsi', index:'IdUtenteEsi', width:200, sortable:false, hidden:true, 
    stype:'select', searchoptions:{dataUrl:'include/dettagli/trovautenti.php'},
    editable:true, edittype:'select', 
    editoptions:{
        dataUrl:'include/dettagli/trovautenti.php',
        dataEvents: [
          {type: 'change',
            fn: function (e) {                      
                $("#tr_TipoCella").load('include/dettagli/trovatipicella.php?IdUtente=' + e.target.value);                    
            }
          }
    ]
    },
    editrules:{required: true, edithidden: true}
  },
  {name:'TipoCella', index:'TipoCella', width:200, sortable:false, hidden:true,             
    stype:'select', searchoptions:{dataUrl:'include/dettagli/trovatipicella.php'},
    editable:true, edittype:'select', 
    editoptions:{
        dataUrl:'include/dettagli/trovatipicella.php',
        postData: function (rowid) {
              return {
                action: "getState",
                IdUtente: $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "IdUtenteEsi")
      };
            }
    },
    editrules:{required: true, edithidden: true}
  }
],
editurl:'include/dettagli/grid_esiti_sped.php?idquery=2',
pager: '#pDett',
rowNum:100,
rowList:[10,20,30,50,100],
sortname: '',
sortorder: '',
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,    
caption: 'Service status',
autowidth:false,   
shrinkToFit: false,    
forceFit:false,
width:'860',
height:'200',
altRows: false,
hiddengrid:false,
hidegrid:false
```

});

Comment: i changed the dataevent like this: $("#tr_TipoCella > .DataTD > .FormElement").load('include/dettagli/trovatipicella.php?IdUtente=' + e.target.value); and it looks like it's working. Do you think it's correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. You should use the input element and not the table row

Comment: thank you tony! Last problem i have now is that when i use prev and next inside the edit form the 2 select do not reload from php and do not call any event. how can I force the update when hitting prev or next?

Comment: If you use Guriddo jqGrid one possible solution is to use the afterclickPgButtons event in edit form. For more information see events [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#edit-grid-row)

Comment: thank you for the tip. now select does reload but it does not position on the right index (it does not use the current row value). this is what i did: afterclickPgButtons: function(whichbutton, form, rowid) {$("#tr_IdEsito > .DataTD > .FormElement").load('include/dettagli/trovaesiti.php?trkeid=' + rowid, function() {});}, in other words it always focus the 1st row of the select

Comment: OK solved. Thank you!!! $("#IdEsito").load('include/dettagli/trovaesiti.php?trkeid=' + rowid, function() {
              jQuery("#IdEsito").val(dati_rigasel.IdEsito).trigger('change');                             
            });